# Http link in the side bar after the sites are rolled-out with https

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, ssl, sidebar

In [Ask Question](/questions/ask), when you click inside the body section, we can see the **How to Format** section in the side bar.

In the list of tips, the last line is:

> ► [basic HTML](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed) also allowed

There still the URL is with `http://` only, where as the same URL is under the **advanced help** -> **HTML** is linked with `https://`.

Clicking on the `http://` URL is redirecting to `https://`, but for consistency the URL in the `basic HTML also allowed` should be updated as `https://`.

The `http://` URL is not yet updated in all the sites.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: http link in side bar]